# Connecting layers in Visio

Tags: visio

I am using an Org Chart in order to diagram our team at work.  For each particular member of the staff, I would like to be able to click their shape file/name on the org chart and tie it to another layer that shows a flowchart of the things they are currently working on.

1. Is this possible?
2. How can I link the shapes on layer 1 to say layer 2 to accomplish that task?
3. Can I use multiple styles of charts across several layers?  For example... Org Chart for layer 1.  Brainstorming/Engineering for layer 2.  And so on.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!